# CKEditor's focus manager focusing on the wrong editor

Tags: ckeditor

I am building a CKEditor plugin, but will not be using CKEditor's dialog.

Instead, I will be using another dialog widget. The dialog contains a text input and a few checkboxes.

This is in what I am doing:

```
var dialogue = Y.one('#blah'); //Get the dialog node using YUI

CKEditor.plugins.add('myplugin', {
   init: function(editor){
      editor.focusManager.add(new CKEDITOR.dom.element(dialogue.getDOMNode()), true);
   }
}
```

I have 2 CKEditor instances on the page which are created using `CKEditor.inline()`.

The problem is that when I interact or focus on the text inputs or checkboxes in the dialogue, it always focuses on the second editor even though I am supposed to be focused on the first editor.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Do those two editors share the same dialog? If so, then you may need to add and remove it to the focus manager depending on which editor is currently focused. And also check if focus is fired on your dialog node.

Comment: Yes, both editors share the same dialog. Your comment makes sense. Can you add it as an answer, so that I can accept? :)